# foreach loop begins at last element

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

My `foreach` loop begins at last element.  I have an array `$gridRows` within object `$grid` that is currently set up like so:

```
$grid
    gridRows
        2
            gridCells
                1
                2
                3
        3
            gridCells
                1
                2
```

gridRow 2 has 3 gridCells in it and gridRow 3 has 2 gridCells.

However, when I iterate through it, the first foreach goes to gridRow 3 first.  It still iterates over gridRow 2 but it does it second.

```
$gridRows = $grid->getGridRows();
foreach ($gridRows as $rowKey => $rowValue) {
    $gridCells = $rowValue->getGridCells();
    foreach ($gridCells as $cellKey => $cellValue) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

What gives?  I tried using `sort($grid, SORT_NUMERIC)` but I get the same effect.

Result of print_r($gridRows):

```
Array (
    [3] => GridRow Object (
        [gridCells:GridRow:private] => Array (
            [2] => GridCell Object ( ... )
            [1] => GridCell Object ( ... )
        )
    )
    [2] => GridRow Object (
        [gridCells:GridRow:private] => Array (
            [1] => GridCell Object ( ... )
            [2] => GridCell Object ( ... )
            [3] => GridCell Object ( ... )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I don't understand, what you are trying to do?
just echo the row? Or save it to an array?!

Comment: `sort()` expects an array - you're passing in an object. `foreach()` is going to iterate the object elements in their internal order. If you're adding an iterator interface, then it'll be up to that interface to return the elements in "sorted" order

Comment: Thanks Marc B, I think my solution is that I need to sort $gridRows, not $grid.

Comment: Haudegen I'm not sure why it matters what I'm trying to do in the second foreach, I was already at the wrong row.

Comment: -3 is harsh!  Genuine oversight.

Comment: What is the result of doing `print_r($gridRows)`? Are your values in the proper order there?

Comment: Thanks ckpepper02, edited the question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to being an object not an array. Use a numerically indexed array to maintain the order you want.